# Find out which user created a category or tag?

Tags: categories, tags

We recently had an employee create inappropriate categories on our site as a way to retaliate against one of our managers. We are looking to figure out who is responsible. I have super admin, as well as database access. Is there a way to find out this information, such as user_id who created it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no WordPress-specific way of doing this - unless you have [Stream](https://wordpress.org/plugins/stream/) installed. If you don't, you might want to think about installing it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a tool. Do you know if there is a way to cross reference server logs with mysql logs of the database entry being added?